Create raydium pool and how to build arg ownerInfo?
tokenAccounts: [],
// how to get token accounts?
// interface TokenAccount { programId: PublicKey, pubkey: PublicKey, accountInfo: SplAccount}
I don't know how to build this arg, pls
const createPoolV4Instruction = await Liquidity.makeCreatePoolV4InstructionV2Simple({
        connection,
        programId: MAINNET_PROGRAM_ID.AmmV4,
        marketInfo: {
            marketId: marketId,
            programId: MAINNET_PROGRAM_ID.OPENBOOK_MARKET,
        },
        baseMintInfo: baseTokenInfo,
        quoteMintInfo: quoteTokenInfo,
        baseAmount: new BN(500000000 * Math.pow(10, 9)),
        quoteAmount: new BN(1 * Math.pow(10, 9)),
        startTime: new BN(Math.floor(Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60)),
        ownerInfo: {
            feePayer: userWallet.publicKey,
            wallet: userWallet.publicKey,
            
            tokenAccounts: [],
            // how to get token accounts?
            // interface TokenAccount { programId: PublicKey, pubkey: PublicKey, accountInfo: SplAccount}
            
            useSOLBalance: true,
        },
        associatedOnly: false,
        checkCreateATAOwner: true,
        makeTxVersion: TxVersion.LEGACY,
        feeDestinationId: new PublicKey('7YttLkHDoNj9wyDur5pM1ejNaAvT9X4eqaYcHQqtj2G5'), // only mainnet use this
    });


